# How to generate a number of ember-power-select using each loop?

Tags: ember.js

I am suing code below to generate a list of `ember-power-select` component.

```
{{#each query_params as |param|}}
    <div>
        <label for="">{{param.param}}</label>

        {{#power-select
            options=param.options
            selected=option
            onchange=(action (mut selectedName))
            allowClear=true
            class="bar-query--inputs-auto"
            as |name|
        }}
            {{name}}
        {{/power-select}}
    </div>
{{/each}}
```

However, `selected=option` makes all the generated `power-select` component share the same selected property `option`. The effect is whenever anyone select's value changes all others selects value will get updated as well.

How should I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{{#each query_params as |param|}}
    <div>
        <label for="">{{param.param}}</label>

        {{#power-select
            options=param.options
            selected=param.selected
            onchange=(action (mut param.selected))
            allowClear=true
            class="bar-query--inputs-auto"
            as |name|
        }}
            {{name}}
        {{/power-select}}
    </div>
{{/each}}
```

I solved issue by changing `select=option` to `select=param.selected`.